# Differentiability class of solution space of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I confused with the solution space implied by a differential equation. For example, take the heat equation

$$ (\partial_t - \partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2) u(t,x,y) =0 , \qquad (t,x,y)\in (0,\infty ) \times \mathbb{R}^2$$

What does this equation imply for the solution space?

It is said that the appropriate space of functions on the domain $\Omega := (0,\infty ) \times \mathbb{R}^2$ is

$$S(\Omega) = \{u=u(t,x,y)| u,u_t ,u_{xx},u_{yy} \in C^0(\Omega)\}$$

where $C^0(\Omega)$ stands for set of continuous functions on the domain.

Now, as I see, the equation only says that these partial derivatives exist while the above set assumes continuous partial derivative.

Where does the continuity of partial derivatives come from?

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: It's convenient to be clear about the solution space and then what we mean by size of a function, in your case the size would be $\sup|u|+\sup|u_t|+\sup|u_{xx}|+\sup|u_{yy}|$. For example, if you look for a solution by an iterative method, you want to measure if your approximate solutions converge to an actual solution, and you need to measure size of "approximate solutions". If you prefer, you could change your space by the space of measurable functions with some notion of size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function $u(t,x,y)$ is locally integrable. So it seems that it's not necessary to assume continuity of partial derivatives. Am I right?